# setWidgetFormDate in Symfony - generate option

Tags: php, html, symfony1, symfony-1.4

if a set widget in form:

```
$this->setWidget('add_date', new sfWidgetFormDate(array(' 'years' => array('10','20','30'))));
```

this generated:

```
<option value="0">10</option>
<option value="1">20</option>
<option value="2">30</option>
```

how can i make to something:

```
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
```

?

thx!

Comment: You have an extra ' in the start of your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...by making the array associative:

```
array('10' => '10', '20' => '20', '30' => '30')
```